# PHP delete image from folder where name not in tables

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to delete images from a folder that are not in a table
I am one line away from a solution
I don't know how to compare the tale query results to the image folder content
This is what I have

```
$link = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die("Unable to Connect to '$dbhost'");

$like = scandir('users/russromei');



 foreach ($like as $thisFile) {

   $rs = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT value FROM ppbv79_listings_media WHERE value like %$thisFile%");
     if($thisFile != "." and $thisFile != ".."){   
       echo $thisFile."<br>";
**** NEED TO COMPARE $thisfile with $rs???
   /*  if($thisFile != "." and $thisFile != ".."){   
       unlink ('sfbuyer/' . $thisFile);

}  */

    }
 }
```

Comment: research comparing two arrays. Fix the syntax and typo bugs in your code. Properly turn the `mysqli_query` into a **mysqli result**

Comment: I don't see any bugs, it runs as written. I don't know php , just need the tweak to make the unlink happen

Comment: You don't need line 4. Delete it. Your code may be at risk of injection attack (if certain file names have certain characters....

Comment: ok, I did that,

Answer (score 4):

Use prepared statements, as @Martin said your code can be vulnerable  to SQL injection. Beside that, here's a quick example how to delete files that don't exist in that database.

Let's say you have the following table

```
------------------------
| ID  |   file         |
------------------------
| 0   |  img1.png      |
| 1   |  img2.png      |
| 3   |  someimage.png |
------------------------
```

and you have a folder (`img`) containing these images :

```
img1.png, img2.png, someimage.png, random.png
```

Here, you have two choices; one is to get every image in the file and check if it exist in the database, if it doesn't then delete it.

*Or* you can select all images from database and removing the non-existant ones (and that's what I'm going to do here).

```
<?php 
 // first put all files into an array 
 $images = scandir('img');

 // create a new empty array that going to hold all files from database 
 $files = [];
 // new we select all files from database 
 // first make your query 
 $query = 'SELECT `file` FROM `myTable`';

 // create mysqli object 
 $mysqli = new Mysqli('localhost','user','password','database');

 // even though this query is not vulnerable to SQL injections
 // I'm going to use a prepared statement 
 $stmt  = $mysqli->prepare($query);
 $stmt->execute();
 $stmt->bind_result($file);
 while($stmt->fetch()){ // insert all files into the array we created earlier
    $files[] = $file;
 }

 $stmt->close();
 $mysqli->close();


 // now you have an array of all files from database and images in folder 
 // we are going to go through each image to check if it exist in the database 
 foreach($images as $img) 
 {
     if(!in_array($img,$files)) {
        // delete file 
        unlink('img/'.$img);
        print("Deleted file [". $img ."]\n");
      } 
 } 
 unset($img);
```

And that shall do it.

Comment: I put in some minor code tweaks but that's a decent answer `:-)`

Comment: Outstanding, this is exactly what I needed! Thank you @azjezz
And thank you martin for your help as well

Comment: @azjezz OK getting this error rse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in /home1/americans/public_html/stampfair.com/users/cron1_delete_images.php on line 37 in this code  // now you have an array of all files from database and images in folder 
 // we are gonna go threw each image to check if it exist in the database 
 foreach($images as $img) 
 {
     if(!in_array($img,$files) {
        // delete file 
        unlink('sfbuyer/'.$img);
        print("Delete file [". $img ."]\n");
 } 
 } 
 unset($img);

Comment: @Russ , i don't know if its too late, but it was a syntax error, i forgot to add ')' before '{' , it should work fine now